# A problem about positive-define

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, and let $h$ be the maximal eigenvalue of $A$.

Claim: $hE-A$ is positive-define, where E is the identity matrix.

I know that if $x$ is a eigenvector of $A$, then $x^T(hE-A)x \ge 0.$

But I have no idea that how to prove the case when $x$ is not a eigenvector.

Can someone give me a hint or a solution to this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the characteristic polynomial of $hE-A$, you have
$$\det(hE-A-\lambda E)=\det((h-\lambda )E-A).$$ So the eigenvalues of $hE-A$ are of the form $h-\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Thus $hE-A$ is symmetric and all its eigenvalues are nonnegative.

Comment: Wow, this proof is elegant. But I think you can change the character t into other character, it may cause misunderstanding. Thank you Martin :)

Comment: As you wish :) $\ $

Comment: Emmm, my meaning is that you can use $t$ in the equation involving determinant and use other character such as $\lambda$ to represent the eigenvalue of A... But It’s fine...

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric, there exists a orthogonal basis of eigenvectors of $A$ so every vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as the linear combination of eigenvectors of $A$. This follows from the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices.

Comment: Emmm, I know this result. But I think $(x+y)^TA(x+y) \neq x^TAx+y^TAy$, am I right? Then how we go on the proof with the spectral theorem?

Comment: I realize that if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, then the equality mentioned above holds. I know how to do it now. Thank you Václav.

Comment: You're welcome!